# Resources for animations in WPF/Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, animation

I'm looking for some good resources to ramp up on the animation/storyboard concepts used in WPF/Silverlight. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one link posted was WPF specific. For Silverlight here are a few other resources.

- [MSDN Animation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189019(VS.95).aspx)
- [Silverlight SDK Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/03/21/silverlight-animations-a-walkthrough.aspx)
- [Adam Kinney Animations Hands on Lab](http://adamkinney.com/blog/346/default.aspx)
- [Nikhil's Effects and Transitions](http://www.nikhilk.net/Silverlight-Effects-Transitions.aspx) (Advanced)

There a lots more out there, but these are a few goods ones I found.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/wpf/IntroductionToWPFAnimations.aspx) site had some good resources that covered some of the information I was looking for.