# Looking for samples of WPF / Silverlight popup animations

Tags: wpf, silverlight, animation, popup

Can anyone recommend a site or application that demonstrates various animations for popup windows? I've seen so many smart apps over the years but now can't locate ones with animated popups. Given my zero artistic skills, I'd be happy to borrow other people's ideas.
Thanks

Comment: I've always been partial to Microsoft Outlook 2007+. :)

Comment: Also, check the answers to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/277168/238688

Answer (score 0):

I came across this today,

[blacklight](http://blacklight.codeplex.com/)

[Drag DockPanel](http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/)

Comment: Some good stuff there but no popup examples. I found these though: http://sachabarber.net/?p=580 and http://kevindockx.blogspot.com/2008/12/silverlight-scale-from-sender-popup.html